# I am filing a travel insurance claim. When should I cancel my reservations?

Tags: air-travel, insurance, cancellations, travel-insurance-claim

My cruise was canceled due to a hurricane, which should be covered by my travel insurance. I requested compensation for the flight and hotel reservations that I no longer need. I sent them proof that I had the reservations, but I'm concerned that if I cancel the reservations, the insurance company won't find them when they are investigating. What should I do?

Comment: What class of ticket and hotel? In other words, would you be getting a full, partial or no refund if you cancel? The insurance will only pay out for your loss, so if cancelling gives you any amount of refund then you should take that - you will still have evidence the reservations existed, and you will now have evidence of actual loss.

Comment: Cancelling a reservation doesn't destroy all records of the reservation being made. The insurance company can certainly find out from the hotel/airline if such reservations existed after they were cancelled.

Comment: Most if not all airlines are waiving cancellation fees for flights that may be affected by the current hurricanes (flights which in some cases will not take place).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you suffered reduced or no loss, i.e., you were able to cancel at no cost to you, or for a fee, the insurer would expect you to do so and reservations alone are not proof of loss.

You’ll need to provide proof of loss (receipts, sworn statements, etc.) As example, [AIG Travel Guard](https://www.travelguard.com/aboutus/claims/claimstg) claims require:

- Trip Invoice/Confirmation showing details of Trip (what/where/when), value of claimed trip component, and airline e-ticket and confirmation/reservation numbers
- Proof of payment for claimed expenses (Paid Trip Invoice, Credit Card, and/or Bank Statement)
- Documentation showing any received or expected settlements, refunds, or credits for this loss from any other party.